# About "wal_buffers" of Postgresql-11 with "synchronous_commit=off"

Tags: postgresql, performance-tuning, write-ahead-logging

Last days I tuned my PG11 for a lots of huge writing transactions, and got a amazing result.

The only warry in my mind is that whether there is more risk of lossing data when I turned off `synchronous_commit`, and used a large `wal_buffers` value.

Comment: @mustaccio That's not true, see the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turing off synchronous_commit will absolutely risk your recent data, as clearly described by the big CAUTION box in [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-async-commit.html).

Answer (score 1):

If `synchronous_commit = off`, you always risk losing data.

There are two parameters that influence how much you can lose: `wal_writer_delay` and `wal_writer_flush_after`. `wal_buffers` could only have an impact in the unlikely event that you set it smaller than `wal_writer_flush_after`.